# How to pass list of values into rdd in json+sparksql

Tags: apache-spark-sql

How to pass  list of values into 
    rdd = sqlContext.jsonFile("tmp.json")

I have list `list1=["name","age","gener",........]`

```
rdd_new=rdd.map(lambda x:x.(i want all list values)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean here. If you want to use the external list that you have in your map function then make the list a broadcast variable so that a read only copy of the list is available to all the functions. Here is an example:

Broadcast> broadlist = sc.broadcast(list1);
        final List query_list = broadlist.value();

Now you can access query_list in your map function as if it was a global variable.
Please tell me if this is what you wanted.

Comment: >>> from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
     >>> sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
     >>> rdd =sqlContext.jsonFile("tmp.json") 
     >>> rdd_new= rdd.map(lambda x:x.name,x.age) 
Its working properly.But there is **list of values** 
    list1=["name","age","gene","xyz",.....] 
When I am passing
  

     For each_value in list1:
         `rdd_new=rdd.map(lambda x:x.each_valuefrom list1)` I am getting error